# fadeOut, fadeIn and stop

Tags: javascript, jquery, fadein, fadeout

How do I make my image fade in and stop using the code below? what do I add to it?
Thanks in advance for any correct answers it is much appreciated!

HTML:

```
<div class="fadeImg" >
    <img src="images/25sprout.jpg">
    <img style="display:none;" src="images/alex.jpg">
    <img style="display:none;" src="images/thundersha.jpg">
    <img style="display:none;" src="images/cathy.jpg">
    <img style="display:none;" src="images/david.jpg">
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/package/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $next = 1;          // fixed, please do not modfy;
    $current = 0;       // fixed, please do not modfy;
    $interval = 4000;   // You can set single picture show time;
    $fadeTime = 800;    // You can set fadeing-transition time;
    $imgNum = 5;        // How many pictures do you have

    $(document).ready(function(){
        //NOTE : Div Wrapper should with css: relative;
        //NOTE : img should with css: absolute;
        //NOTE : img Width & Height can change by you;
        $('.fadeImg').css('position','relative');
        $('.fadeImg img').css({'position':'absolute','width':'332px','height':'500px'});

        nextFadeIn();
    });

    function nextFadeIn(){
        //make image fade in and fade out at one time, without splash vsual;
        $('.fadeImg img').eq($current).delay($interval).fadeOut($fadeTime)
            .end().eq($next).delay($interval).hide().fadeIn($fadeTime, nextFadeIn);

        // if You have 5 images, then (eq) range is 0~4 
        // so we should reset to 0 when value > 4; 
        if($next < $imgNum-1){ $next++; } else { $next = 0;}
        if($current < $imgNum-1){ $current++; } else { $current =0; }
    };
</script>
```

Comment: I copied and pasted this in my code and just changed the name *fadeImg* to *topHeroImage* which is the name of my class. I also am using two images not 5 so i changed $imgNum=2.  I am extremely new to javascript however i am learning. I know that there is a way to add .stop into it, i just dont know where to make it stop looping.

Comment: Your stated requirement doesn't appear to match the code.  Just do `$("#id").fadeIn();`.   Perhaps you could explain what you're trying to do and why you think this plugin solves it rather than some simpler code.

Comment: here is what i have been coding: http://assets.daddario.com/landing_calftone/calftone_landing.html The top header image has the looping pngs i dont know how to write javacript or jquery so i found this on 25sproutLab and it seemed to work great as far as starting on the first png and then fading to the next png, however i dont know how to make it stop on the second image and stay stopped instead of looping. im not sure how to write the full code. im so sorry i am new at this. i appreciate you trying to work it out with me. @freedom-m

Comment: It's a shame you found this code, it's not particularly elegant and will likely give you some bad practices.  Keep looking at other code as you learn.  But most of all, make sure you have fun learning.

Comment: Thanks so much, I will try and add this and see what happens, I am definitely having fun, and it is most definitely satisfying when everything works properly.

Comment: Glad to hear you're enjoying learning! Glad you found a solution that works as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your simplest option is to stop when `$current` matches `$imgNum`:

```
 function nextFadeIn() {
    if ($current >= $imgNum) return;
    //make image fade in and fade out at one time, without splash vsual;
```

Although purists might not like this as it means an extra iteration of nextFadeIn(), it should cover what you need with minimal changes.